# Distinguish between user and framework setting values?

Tags: hibernate, persistence, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA/Hibernate and I have a persistent worker object that does a countdown.  It's modeled using 2 int values: `totalPages` and `remainingPages`.  When the object is created it assures that `total == remaining`, and each time a page is processed, remainingPages is decremented:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class WorkerState {
  private int totalPages;

  private int remainingPages;

  /** Constructor for JPA. */
  protected WorkerState() {
  }

  public WorkerState(int totalPages) {
    setTotalPages(totalPages);
  }

  private void setRemainingPages(int remainingPages) {
    this.remainingPages = remainingPages;
  }

  public void setTotalPages(int totalPages) {
    this.totalPages = totalPages;
    setRemainingPages(totalPages);
  }

  public void decrementRemainingPages() {
    this.remainingPages--;
  }

}
```

Currently, `setTotalPages()` also calls `setRemainingPages()`. However, I am thinking this will get me into trouble if the object is persisted while processing. If `remainingPages` is less than `totalPages` and the object is persisted, `remainingPages` value will be unknown when it is refetched (depending on the order of Hibernate calling the setters).

If I could know that Hibernate is invoking `setTotalPages()`, then I could avoid resetting remainingPages. Is there a way to do that?

One thought was to make the public method called `addToPages()` and make the `setTotalPages` method private like `setRemainingPages` is.  The only downside is the weird semantics of setting an arbitrary total (`addToPages(myNewTotal-getTotalPages())`), but I guess it's not the worst thing I've seen.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are talking about without a litte snippet of your code. Especially two of your statements are unclear to me: _persisted while processing_ - does this mean you have no control when the entity is persisted? And _Hibernate is invoking `setTotalPages()`_ - Why should Hibernate invoke a custom method in an entity?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke, "persisted while processing" - The 'while processing' part means 'while 0 < remainingPages < totalPages'.  IOW, if total =5 and remaining = 3, then loading from store would set remaining = 5 if setTotalPages() includes the side-effect of keeping remaining in sync (which you'd want to do while changing the value prior to beginning the countdown).

Comment: @TobiasLiefke, "Hibernate is invoking setTotalPages()" - that's how it's annotated to create the Entity from data store (annotations on setter/getter pairs).  And as a matter of fact, Hibernate will try to invoke *any* method called setXXX so you have to explicitly tell it NOT to do so if you want to use the word 'set' in your method names!

Comment: That is something that would be easy to understand, if you would provide the relevant code blocks. I've added your described code (I hope I've got the meaning right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see there are two options:

1. As you already mentioned you could provide a private setter without sideeffects. But in that case I would call the public method differently:

   ```
   private void setTotalPages(int totalPages) {
     this.totalPages = totalPages;
   }

   public void resetTotalPages(int totalPages) {
     this.totalPages = totalPages;
     this.remainingPages = totalPages;
   }
   ```
2. You can set a marker as soon as your object was fully initialized by Hibernate using `@PostLoad`:

   ```
   public class WorkerState {
     private boolean initialized;

     ...

     public WorkerState(int totalPages) {
       initialized = true;
       setTotalPages(totalPages);
     }

     @PostLoad
     private void init() {
       this.initialized = true;
     }

     public void setTotalPages(int totalPages) {
       this.totalPages = totalPages;
       if (initialized) {
         setRemainingPages(totalPages);
       }
     }

     ...

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Tobias. I decided to go with option 1 because `total` and `remaining` are essentially just implementation details of the `pages` property.  So `setPages()` is the public API, and `total` and `remaining` are managed clearly and distinctly either by Hibernate, the internal processing, or the user via `setPages()`.